# CSS - Android stock browser behaving unexpectedly

Tags: android, css, html, less

Compared to all other browsers I've tested this one, the stock Android browser has a weird way of dealing with my image sizing. Here is the HTML and LESS that I'm using.

Here are some **screenshots:** Android first, then Chrome on Windows

**Android 4.1.1**
[image]

**Chrome 26 on Windows 7**
[image]

They should be square but they are clearly not.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

The website is at http://music.fhmp.net

```
<div class="album">
   <img class="album_image" src="./images/albums-low/heart_of_nowhere.jpg">
   <div class="album_inner">
      <p class="album_artist_title">
         <span>Heart of Nowhere</span> (2013)<br>Noah And The Whale
      </p>
      <div class="streams">
         <div class='spotify'>
            <a href='spotify:album:0t0QkoTnDz5uj5I92C7wwE'>
               <img src='./images/icons/spotify.png'>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class='grooveshark'>
            <a href='http://grooveshark.com/#!/album/Heart+Of+Nowhere/8927514'>
               <img src='./images/icons/grooveshark.png'>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class='youtube missing'>
            <a>
               <img src='./images/icons/youtube.png' alt=''>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class='rdio'>
            <a href='http://www.rdio.com/artist/Noah_and_the_Whale/album/Heart_Of_Nowhere/'>
               <img src='./images/icons/rdio.png'>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <p class="added">+ 12 May 2013</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

LESS: (which is quite messy)

```
body {
    background-color: #111;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Avenir', sans-serif;
}

.albums{
    padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.border-box-sizing{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}


.album {
    .border-box-sizing;
    float: left;
    color: #eee;
    padding: 5px 5px 0px 0px ;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: none;
    position: relative;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px){ width: 100%; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px){   width: 50%; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1200px){  width: 33.33%; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1600px){     width: 25%; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1601px) and (max-width: 2000px){     width: 20%; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 2001px) and (max-width: 2400px){     width: 16.66%; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 2401px){ width: 14.29%; }

}

.album_inner{
    .border-box-sizing;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

.album p{
    margin: 0;
}



.album > img {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #234;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.streams{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 56px 36px 16px 36px;
    .border-box-sizing;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    > div {

        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        float: left;

        &.missing {
            opacity: 0.1;
            cursor: default;
        }

        > a {

            width: 80%;
            height: 80%;
            margin: 10%;
            display: block;

            > img {
                border-radius: 4px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    }
}

.added {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 5;
}

.album_artist_title {
    color: #eee;
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;

    > span {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px){ font-size: 13px;}
    @media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 600px){   font-size: 11px; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 601px){ font-size: 13px; }
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Avenir';
    src: url('./fonts/avenir/AVENIRLTSTD-MEDIUM.eot');
    src: url('./fonts/avenir/AVENIRLTSTD-MEDIUM.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./fonts/avenir/AVENIRLTSTD-MEDIUM.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say those `height: 100%` on `streams > div > a > img` have something to do with it... what if you give the images a `height: auto`?